# IntelliJ run spring boot JPA application says not-null property references a null or transient value , But working fine from terminal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea, flyway

I have a microservice project using Spring Boot: 2.6.2, JPA, and H2 DB with JAVA 17.
when I run my project from IntelliJ as an application from configuration it shows the below exception while inserting data into DB:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

But when I run this project from the command line or STS it's working fine, There is no exception. And entry was inserted properly.
I am using H2 Db as a datasource at my application.yml for local run.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=5
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: admin
    password: admin
```

In this application.yml flyway is also used but that is only for the dev env profile.
The entity that is showing issue for :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity

@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends Basics {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "ID",
      sequenceName = "ID_SEQ")
  @GeneratedValue(
      strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "ID")
  @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "USER_ID")
  private Integer userID;


  @Column(name = "HOST_DATE")
  private LocalDate hostDate;


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "Host_DATA_ID")
  private POHostData poHostData;

  @OneToOne(
      mappedBy = "user",
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JsonManagedReference("Manager_Result")
  private ManagerResult ManagerResult;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference("Basicuser_Authorisation")
  private List<Authorisation> authorisation;

  @OneToOne(
      mappedBy = "user",
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @Valid
  private HostLineUser hostLineUser; // for this hostLineUser its showing error
}
```

And the HostLineUser Entity is

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class HostLineUser {

  @Column(name = "COUNTRY_OF_HOST", length = 2, columnDefinition = "char")
  private String countryOfHost;

  @Column(name = "HOST_CODE")
  private Integer hostCode;


  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  private Employee employee;

}
```

Comment: Does it help if you use Spring Boot run configuration type instead of Application?

Comment: But I am using IntelliJ community version. That doesn't have Spring Boot run configuration.